# Transformar milisegundos de UTC em outros Time Zone

Tags: java

Recebo de um serviço a data em milisegundos e UTC.

Preciso transformar no Time Zone do Usuário.

Para isso fiz o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Milisegundos está em UTC...
    long time = 1457037493000L; 
    String format = "HH:mm:ss";

    SimpleDateFormat sdfUtc = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
    sdfUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    SimpleDateFormat sdfLocal = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
    sdfLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); // Meu TimeZone é -3...

    System.out.println("Local : "+sdfLocal.format(time));
    System.out.println("UTC : "+sdfUtc.format(time));

}
```

Resultado:

> Local : 17:38:13
>   UTC : 20:38:13

Na verdade `17:38:13` é o horario em UTC!

E o local seria `14:38:13` pois meu Time Zone é -3.

como faço para corrigir a data em UTC para o Time Zone do usuário?

Comment: `1457037493000` é equivalente a 20:38:13 em UTC - https://jsfiddle.net/mgvvsubq/ - o seu código está imprimindo o que ele deveria.

Comment: Exato, minha dúvida é como imprimir no Time Zone do usuário.

Comment: `sdfLocal.format(time)` te dá o a hora no teu time zone, não? Se aquele valor é equivalente a 20:38, e você está em UTC-0300, o horário do seu time zone é 17:38. Não foi isso que você recebeu quando imprimiu `"Local : "+sdfLocal.format(time)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma, adicionando o `getOffset` do TimeZone.

```
  public static long convertToTimeZoneDefault(final long time, final TimeZone zone){
        final Date localTime = new Date(time);
        final Date fromGmt = new Date(time + zone.getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
        return fromGmt.getTime();
    }
```